# React Native Metro Server doesn't launch after npm run android

Tags: javascript, react-native

`info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1158 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...`

after starting JS Server Metro doesnt launch (without errors), but app installs successfully.
OS: Ubuntu 20
React Native: 0.62
Node: v14.4.0
npm: 6.14.5

Comment: Have you try npm start ? If the app already launched run npm start and open the app and reload

Comment: Akila Devinda oh, thanks :) youre my hero

Comment: Glad it helps :)